# Separation of directives into modules AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Someone answer on my very important question. :)

I has been working on various projects in [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs)for several months.

I have problem of code breakdown on different structures, modules, directives.

Let's say I have a project which have, 
- a top menu with a lot of functionality that repeats itself, 
- side menu that contains a lot of functions
- board with lists and cards, the possibility of their transfer,
- Clicking on the card opens a modal window which also has a lot of functionality,

The frightening thing is that I have it all in one controller and in one [html](/questions/tagged/html)template. :D

And I thought that I would create separate directives also with separate controllers for each of these things.
Each directive will have:

**directiv**

```
restrict : 'E',
templateUrl,
controller: function() {}
controllerAs
```

I heard that it is good to do so to separate the menu directive to a separate module.

Could someone tell me if I good thinking or not? If not Could someone tell me how to share it well? for what things?

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe you want to Read [Angular 1 Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md). This could be very helpful when deciding how to organize your code/project.

Comment: Yes I Could, but if someone tell me how to seperatet this file I will know on the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few suggestions for you:

- Split your html file into multiple components (or directives if you are using AngularJS < v1.5) by grouping your html into different sections. Create a component for each section like so:

  ```
  <body>

      <top-menu></top-menu>

      <sidebar></sidebar>

      <board></board>

  </body>
  ```

  Notice how much simpler it is to immediately distinguish the major sections of your UI. Because your components are feature-rich, you can further break down each component into more subcomponents. For example, `topMenu`'s template could be:

  ```
  <ul>
      <a>Link 1</a>
      <a>Link 2</a>
      <a>Link 3</a>
  </ul>

  <search-bar></search-bar>

  <social-media></social-media>

  <chat-box></chat-box>
  ```

  The added benefit is that you can now reuse `searchBar`, `socialMedia`, and `chatBox` throughout your application.
- Because you mentioned that the `topMenu`, `sidebar`, and `board` all have rich functionality, you can organize the major features of your UI by placing each feature into its own module. You could have an `app.topMenu` module, `app.sidebar` module, and `app.board` module. You then declare these modules as dependencies in your main app module like so:

  ```
  angular.module("app", [

      // Module that contains shared modules 
      "app.common",

      // Feature-specific modules
      "app.topMenu",
      "app.sidebar",
      "app.board"
  ]);
  ```

  You can now group all of `topMenu`'s private services and components into `app.topMenu`. For components/directives/modules/services that are shared across your application, you can place those in the `app.common` module.
- Keep your controllers lean by outsourcing reusable logic into services that can be reused throughout your application. For example, if you are making ajax calls in your controllers, move that logic into AngularJS services so that different parts of your application can also make those ajax calls. This can really help keep your code DRY (don't repeat yourself) and maintainable.

For a more complete list on how you can structure and style various parts of your application, see John Papa's AngularJS style guide [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md).

Comment: Hey which is differences between hold a component inside app.common and app.sidebar ? because independently where is component nested, I can  call it anywhere in the app.